# Estimating the order of $t$ from the given inequality

Tags: limits, inequality, asymptotics, estimation

While performing certain calculations in the context of Shannon's counting argument for reversible circuits, I came across the following inequality

$$(2^3!)[(n+3t)]^{3t} \geq \frac{(2^n!)}{2}$$

where $!$ denotes factorial.

How to *estimate* (the order of) $t$ from the above expression (in the asymptotic sense)? I guess the Stirling approximation might be useful somehow.

Comment: "in the asymptotic sense"...  Asymptotic in which combination of {t big, t small}, {n big, n small}?

Comment: @EricTowers I'm trying to express $t$ in terms of $n$ in the limit $n\to \infty$. I guess it should be something like $t$ ~ $2^n$...

Answer (score 1):

Expanding to first order in $n$ and $t$ around $(n,t) = (\infty,0)$, we obtain
$$  t\geq \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi } \left(2^n+1\right)^{2^n+\frac{1}{2}} \exp
   \left(-2^n+\frac{1}{12 \left(2^n+1\right)}-\frac{1}{360
   \left(2^n+1\right)^3}+\frac{1}{1260 \left(2^n+1\right)^5}-\frac{1}{1680
   \left(2^n+1\right)^7}-1\right)-80640}{241920 \log n}  \text{,}  $$
which is 
$$  O\left( \frac{(2^n)^{2^n + 1/2}\mathrm{e}^{-2^n}}{\log n} \right) \text{.}  $$So the big piece is $(2^n)^{2^n}$ as expected from the [Stirling approximation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html) (eqn. (22)), $2^n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi} (2^n)^{2^n+1/2} \mathrm{e}^{-2^n}$.

---

Added in response to comment...

This is computed using Mathematica 11.3.

```
Assuming[{n > 1},
  Simplify[
    Reduce[
      Normal[Series[
        8! (n + 3 t)^(3 t) - (2^n)!/2, 
        {n, \[Infinity], 1}, 
        {t, 0, 1}
      ]] >= 0, 
      t, 
      Reals
    ]
  ]
]
TeXForm[%]

(* Output:  t >= (-80640 + (1 + 2^n)^(1/2 + 2^n) E^(-1 - 2^n - 1/(1680 (1 + 2^n)^7) + 1/(1260 (1 + 2^n)^5) - 1/(360 (1 + 2^n)^3) + 1/(12 (1 + 2^n))) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]])/(241920 Log[n]) *)
(* Output:  t\geq \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi } \left(2^n+1\right)^{2^n+\frac{1}{2}} \exp \left(-2^n+\frac{1}{12 \left(2^n+1\right)}-\frac{1}{360 \left(2^n+1\right)^3}+\frac{1}{1260 \left(2^n+1\right)^5}-\frac{1}{1680 \left(2^n+1\right)^7}-1\right)-80640}{241920 \log (n)} *)
```

It can be a good idea to swap the ordering of the expansion variables to see if, and if so, why, there are changes.  In this case, there are none.

```
...
        {t, 0, 1}
        {n, \[Infinity], 1}, 
...

(*  same output  *)
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this result. The approximation of $T$ for the inequality $(n+T)^{2T} \geq 2^{2^n}$ is $2^n/n$ (cf. page 3 of https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-080-great-ideas-in-theoretical-computer-science-spring-2008/lecture-notes/lec7.pdf). I'd expect the $t$ here to be of similar order really; $(2^n)^{2^n}$ is way too big!

Comment: @S.D. : I note that $2^{2^n} \ll 2^n!$.

Comment: I see, thanks. By the way, how did you get that expression for $t$? Mathematica? Could you share your code?

Comment: @S.D. : Code shared.